# MongoDB remove item from array from a selected document

Tags: codeigniter, mongodb

I am developing a web app using Codeigniter and Alex Bilbies MongoDB library.
Each user got a document that contains an item called phones which contains an array of phone numbers. How can I pull an item out of the array from the selected users document?

Thankful for all help!

Comment: Mongo has support of $pull out of the box:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24pull

Comment: Yeah, but can I make a pull on a specific array item?

Answer (score 2):

Even I ran into an issue when directly trying to pull a value from an array using Alex Bilbies MongoDB library.
This approach works for me, first unsetting the value, and then pulling all nulls.

Hope this helps

```
$this->mongo_db->where('items', "5678")->unset_field('items.$')->update('mycollection');
$this->mongo_db->pull('items', NULL)->update('mycollection');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using MongoDB $pull for removing specific array item from array:

```
> db.mycollection.insert({user: "test", items: [1234, 5678, 91011]});
> db.mycollection.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ec3b9af8d1ae67f1fb2b30a"), "user" : "test", "items" : [ 1234, 5678, 91011 ] }
> db.mycollection.update({user: "test"}, {$pull: {items: 5678}});
> db.mycollection.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ec3b9af8d1ae67f1fb2b30a"), "items" : [ 1234, 91011 ], "user" : "test" }
```

Comment: Nice. But how can I pull from an array of a specific document?

Comment: well, when using modifier operators you do not need to specify whole document you need to specify only criteria and specify field which you need to modify. In terms of PHP this would look like: $coll->update(array('username' => 'jamesbond', array('$pull' => array('items' => 5678)));

Comment: Ok. But what does that look like using Alex Bilbies library?
This does not work: $this -> mongo_db -> pull ('items', $pull) -> update ('market.carts', $query);

Comment: Sorry I do not know anything about this library :( solutions I posted work in mongo shell and PHP driver.